# When will point with velocity hit line?

Tags: geometry

In a 2D world given velocityX and velocityY of a moving point how to find out the time when it hits a line. And how to find out if it won't hit the line. (Start and endpoint of the line and the point of the moving line are given too)

Comment: Constant velocity?

Comment: @Bair yes constant velocity

Comment: Writing up detailed answer. Just give me a few more minutes.

Comment: Find the perpendicular distance from the line. Find component of velocity perpendicular to it. And find the component of gravitational acceleration towards it. Calculate using basic projectile motion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interesting question. I will approach it using parametric definition of a line, since that makes the most sense.
$$\vec r(t)=\vec r_0 +\vec v*t$$
Where $\vec r_0$ is the original of the moving point at time $t=0$. The $\vec v$ is the velocity vector of the moving point. $\vec r(t)$ is therefore the time-dependent position of the moving point. To make this easier, expand into each dimension:
$$X: r_x(t)=r_{0x}+v_x*t$$
$$Y: r_y(t)=r_{0y}+v_y*t$$
Let us assume that the other line is an implicit equation of the form:
$$ax+by=c$$
This allows vertical and horizontal lines. If the moving point touches the line, the time when the x-component reaches the line must be the same time as when the y-component reaches the line. Therefore, plug in the two components and solve for $t$.
$$a*r_x(t)+b*r_y(t)=c \rightarrow a*(r_{0x}+v_x*t)+b*(r_{0y}+v_y*t)=c$$
$$a*r_{0x}+a*v_x*t+b*r_{0y}+b*v_y*t=c \rightarrow (a*v_x+b*v_y)*t=c-a*r_{0x}-b*r_{0y}$$
$$t=\frac{c-a*r_{0x}-b*r_{0y}}{a*v_x+b*v_y}$$
If the denominator becomes 0, then you know that the point never reaches the line. This would also imply that the point is travelling parallel to the line.